# Salesforce SSO setup fails with error: Unable to login using your identity provider

Tags: single-sign-on, identity

I have configured an Elastic SSO Identity Provider, and added Salesforce as a Service Provider. I also configured a Custom Domain. When I access Salesforce custom domain on the browser, it properly redirects to the Elastic SSO Login page. But after login, Salesforce says "Unable to login using your identity provider."

I then go to Elastic SSO Transaction Log, pick up the SAML Response and paste it into Salesforce SAML Assertion Validator in the Single Sign On settings page. Here, I find the following error:

Subject: myname@abcxyz.com

Unable to map the subject to a Salesforce.com user.

Of course, the two are different - My Salesforce ID (if I login directly using https://login.salesforce.com is myname@abc123.com and in the Elastic SSO, it is myname@abcxyz.com

How do I tell Elastic SSO that the name it should assert is myname@abc123.com?
Besides this, I also get the following errors in the SAML Assertion Validator page.

```
<p>
11. Validating the Signature</p>
  <p>Is the response signed? true</p>
  <p>Is the assertion signed? true</p>
  <p>The reference in the response signature is valid</p>
  <p>The signature in the assertion is not valid</p>
  <p>The reference in the assertion signature is valid</p>
  <p>Is the correct certificate supplied in the keyinfo? true</p>
  <p>Signature or certificate problems</p>
  <p>The signature in the response is not valid</p>
```

I am using a self-signed certificate for testing.